# Eloquent update all column fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update all the tables in the Article migration to a specific Boolean value which is set by the user.

I have written this code:

```
public function changeComVote() {
    $data = request()->validate([
        'status' => 'required'
     ]);  
    
     Article::query()->update(['isOnly' => $data['status']]);

     event(new changesMade);
}
```

Although `$data['status']` doesn't get passed inside the query and nothing happens, when i set it manually it works like a charm, what could be the problem?

Comment: remove `query()` method and than perform

Comment: @Shahrukh `query()` use is totally fine here.

Comment: @N69S any reason to use `query()` method

Comment: @Shahrukh faster execution, even if it is some micro seconds (check comment on @ UDIN answer or directly from eloquent model code). The real question is "any reason not to use it ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$data['status']` from request will give you a string as a result, not a boolean.

Try this way

```
 Article::query()->update(['isOnly' => $data['status'] == 'true']);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, weird, i'm using the exact same method in a different function and it works just fine but without the query() method and to update only 1 table.
I used $value = $data['status'] == 'true' ? true : false; and then use this variable instead but still it didn't work although when i dump the value it's either true or false as it is supposed to be

Comment: @Steve how are you checking that it "didnt work" ? There are some details missing here.

Comment: I'm using tinker to check the table value, also this function is getting called with a switch, if the flag isOnly is true in one of the Articles the switch is turned to false and if the flag isOnly is false in all the articles it is turned to true which triggers the parliament vote. For some reason this code above doesn't accept variables?

Comment: have you tried in tinker to run `$data = ['status' => 'true'];` `Article::query()->update(['isOnly' => $data['status'] == 'true']);` if it changes your value, then update your question with missing details.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete that "query()" thing and use this instead

```
Article::update(['isOnly' => $data['status']]);
```

or

```
Article::update(['isOnly' => ($data['status']] === "true"));
```

You can also specify where the row by using id

```
Article::find($id)->update(['isOnly' => ($data['status']] === "true"));
```

Comment: when you call `update()` on the class, the magic method `__callstatic()` will call `query()` then foreward the `update()` call to it. So no need to remove the `query()` method

Comment: Error without query(): Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically